# Jquery - change font color based on value of sql result

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, sql

I'm looking to change the font color of a div using jquery where the div is populated by the output of a SQL query.

I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#foo').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == 'bar') {
            $(this).css('color','orange');
        }
    });
});
```

From a SO search which works fine when the div contains text.

But as this is SQL i'm populating the div with: ".$row['result']."

And this now does not work.  I'm guessing this is because the sql, although being a varchar field is a $variable and isn't 'text' as such?.

I'm sure this is something simple, but i'm struggling to phrase this in google to return anything useful.

Many thanks.

edit

The whole thing is rather long and before i've tried to add the jquery was all working fine, so i'll just post the additions.

This is within the head:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js'></script>";  
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";  
echo "$(document).ready(function(){ $('#foo').each(function(){ if ($(this).text() == 'bar') { $(this).css('color','orange');}});});";
```

Then i echo each row in a while loop:

> $sql = "SELECT...";
>       $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
>       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
>       `echo "<div id='foo'>".$row['result']."</div>";`
>       }

The whole document is wrapped in PHP but its not the source of the issue as if i change the div to contain text rather than ".$row['result']."  then the jquery executes on it just fine.

Comment: SQL (I guess you use PHP?) is server side, and jQuery is client side. Can you post the code (jQuery AND SQL) you use to change the color from SQL?

Comment: #foo represents div's id or any other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving every div the same id ("foo"). An id has to be unique in HTML, you would be better off using a class for this. The way you have it now the `.each()` function would only be called on one element, possibly the first.

Change the HTML output like this:

```
echo "<div class='foo'>".$row['result']."</div>";
```

Then, adapt your selector in jQuery accordingly:

```
$('.foo').each(function(){
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a $.ajax call or just emmbed the value via PHP on page load?

If you use PHP to print the value, I guess you forgott to echo the value:

```
".<?php echo $row['result']?>."
```

Not just:

```
".$row['result']."
```

Comment: edited above to show the sql and how i'm printing it.  Everything's fine on the page before attempting to apply any Jquery to it. Its just that the 'text' is a sql result that is stumping me. Thanks.

Comment: Problem with spaces? ... try $(this).text().trim() == 'bar' . in general it would be more distinct to define css classes instead of checking the content with jquery.